# VHDL Array: Index -10 out of bound 0 to 31999

Tags: vhdl, simulation, ram, hdl, vivado

I have this BRAM implementation

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity BRAM is
    Generic (
           DEPTH  : NATURAL := 32000; -- 128 KB
           WIDTH  : NATURAL := 32
           );
    Port ( CLK   : in  STD_LOGIC;
           WRITE : in  STD_LOGIC;
           ADDRW   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (WIDTH-1 downto 0);
           ADDRR   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (WIDTH-1 downto 0);
           DIN   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (WIDTH-1 downto 0);
           DOUT  : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (WIDTH-1 downto 0)
         );
end BRAM;

architecture BEHAV of BRAM is
type STD_LOGIC_VECTOR_ARRAY is array(0 to DEPTH-1) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal MEMORY : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR_ARRAY;
begin
  process(CLK)
  begin
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
        if WRITE = '1' then
          MEMORY(to_integer(unsigned(ADDRW))) <= Din;
        end if;
        DOUT <= MEMORY(to_integer(unsigned(ADDRR)));
    end if;
  end process;
end BEHAV;
```

For indexing the BRAM with STD_LOGIC_VECTORs I use

```
MEMORY(to_integer(unsigned(ADDRR)))
```

Now sometimes the ADDRR (or ADDWR) is a large 32 bit number for example 0xfffffff6.
But the "to_integer" conversion interprets this as "-10" which leads to an out of bounds error.

[image]

I can't index arrays with unsigned numbers. So how do I solve this?

Comment: What do you want `0xfffffff6` to be interpreted as?

Comment: @Trebor As 4294967286

Comment: Wouldn't that be out of bounds also?

Comment: @Trebor Yes true, but I can change DEPTH to 4294967295. Then it wouldnt. My main goal here is to use ADDRW and ADDRR as *unsigned* indexes to the array

Comment: Integers have the range –2147483647 and +2147483647 inclusive.   So your expected number is too big.   Type natural goes from 0 to +2147483647.    So it is indeed an error.   I doubt it is a real issue as Is there a BRAM that can have 4 billion bits?

Comment: Why are you addressing non-existent memory? Historically you'd either use device select and/or write enable steering to control valid accesses.  For 128MB the memory array size (DEPTH) in 32 element (bit) words would be 32768, a power of two without regard to claiming a slightly smaller array size. The port addresses would physically have 15 elements (bits). Here your behavioral description doesn't match the physical implementation which depends on DEPTH.

Comment: For that memory, WIDTH ought to be 15 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found something that works in simulation

```
process(CLK)
begin
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
        if WRITE = '1' then
            if (to_integer(UNSIGNED(ADDRW)) >= 0) and (to_integer(UNSIGNED(ADDRW)) < DEPTH) then
                MEMORY(to_integer(UNSIGNED(ADDRW))) <= DIN;
            end if;
        end if;
        if (to_integer(UNSIGNED(ADDRR)) >= 0) and (to_integer(UNSIGNED(ADDRR)) < DEPTH) then
            DOUT <= MEMORY(to_integer(UNSIGNED(ADDRR)));
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

I would still prefer a cleaner way. Especially since I want to synthesize this project and in hardware unsigned array indexing is semantic wise not an issue. But I think the "if"s will still get synthesized.

Comment: The left hand side of the AND condition of the if statement is only the MS element of the address. The right hand side is the address elements necessary to delimit DEPTH (which if a power of two is the different in the number of address elements to address the array and the actual address length). You've basically internalized device selection in a larger address space.

Comment: I also found out that this problem seems to be a bug. According to https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/packages/numeric_std.vhd when the input to TO_INTEGER is an UNSIGNED the result cannot be negative, which my simulator reports it is.